# Python Codewars: can someone explain how/why this happens?

Tags: python, arrays, multiple-occurrence

I'm doing Codewars and got stuck at this simple question. The question was:

> Your goal in this kata is to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from
> another and returns the result.
> It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b keeping their order.
> If a value is present in b, all of its occurrences must be removed from the other.

This is what I've tried:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    if a == []: return b
    if b == []: return a
    for occurrence in b:
      if occurrence in a:
        a.remove(occurrence)
    return a
```

and for some reason I got 2 failed tests, the requirements for those failed tests are:

```
a was [1,2,2], b was [2], expected [1]: [1, 2] should equal [1]

a was [], b was [1,2], expected []: [1, 2] should equal []
```

can anyone help me and also explain if possible? any help is appreciated.
edit: my excuse is that I'm a beginner to Python so, sorry if this question has super obvious errors/mistakes

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `return [value for value in a if value not in b]` be enough?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include an answer, you are able to answer your own question if you wish. Or if picchiolu's answer works for you then you can accept it (little green checkmark).

Comment: ah ok, thank you for the suggestion. Also thank you Matthias for the answer. It worked and was way cleaner than my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Here's the code if anyone's stuck on the same question:
The first code was provided by Matthias, which was much cleaner, please use it.

```
def array_diff(a, b):    
    return [value for value in a if value not in b]
    # CREDITS TO MATTHIAS FOR THIS SIMPLE SOLUTION
```

My code, if anyone's interested:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    #if a == []: return b
    #if b == []: return a
    # these if statements are replaced by the"for item in range" code below
    for occurrence in b:
      if occurrence in a:
        for item in range(a.count(occurrence)):
            a.remove(occurrence)
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and modify your code as follows:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    if a == []: return a
    if b == []: return a
    for occurrence in b:
        if occurrence in a:
            a = list(filter(lambda val: val != occurrence, a)
    return a
```

Comment: somehow your answer gave me an error message at the last line. It was an error syntax

Comment: I fixed it. I appreciate your answer though, thanks!

Comment: I think I messed up with the indents. I amended my answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Great! Please, consider selecting my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided did not completely work for me although it was very helpful, this is what i came up with and it worked.
Happy Coding!

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    #your code here
    for i in b: 
        if i == None:
            return a
            break  
        elif i in a:
            for item in range(a.count(i)):
                a.remove(i)
    return a
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

def array_diff(a, b):
# your code here
if a == []: return b
if b == []: return a
b = [2, 4]
newlist = []
for value in b:
if value in a:
a.remove(value)
newlist.append(a)
print(newlist)
array_diff(a=[1,2], b=[2])

Comment: Hello new user! Welcome to StackOverflow :) My question was answered already, but I thank you for your effort. However, please correctly format your code so that it is more readable (You can read this here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Again, thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).